# Calling Erlang functions from NIF

Tags: erlang, erlang-nif

Is it possible to call Erlang functions (callback funs) from NIFs?

I read the doc(http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html), but didn't find how to do that.

Comment: There seem to be some relevant hits when I try `call erlang nif` web search - do any of those give useful info?

Comment: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2018-January/094626.html

Answer (score 10):

No, calling an Erlang function from a NIF isn't possible. You can either implement your functionality in an Erlang function that calls into a private NIF that returns a value indicating whether or not invoking a callback is necessary, or perhaps you could instead send a message to another process using [`enif_send`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html#enif_send) and have it call the callback function for you.